# Toggle text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript. 
I am trying toggle the text on a page using the `replaceChild()` method. I came up with the code below. I don't understand why it will not work. Pls help.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
    function toggleText() {
        var be= document.getElementById("main");
        var b4= be.getElementsByTagName("h1");
        var l8 = document.createElement("h1").innerHTML="After";
        var l88 = document.createElement("h1").innerHTML="Before";
        if (b4[0].innerHTML=="Before"){ 
            be.replaceChild(l8,b4[0]) 
        }
        if (b4[0].innerHTML=="After") {
            be.replaceChild(l88,b4[0]);
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="main" onclick="toggleText()">
        <h1>Before</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @kapa there is a option to edit :)

Comment: Side note. Typo, missing `)` in `if (b4[0].innerHTML=="After" {`

Comment: getElementsByTagName("h1")[0] for the actual element

Comment: @RahilWazir I use it when I find it appropriate, thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CBrone wrote, you have to create h1 instance first, store it to variable and then call innerHML on the variable.

Another problem is if structure. First you replace the element and then test the same element for another condition and do another operation. In this case is better to use `if ... else if ...` statement instead of `if ... if ...`, which is the root of your problem.

Here is working `toggleText` function

```
function toggleText() {
    var be= document.getElementById("main");
    var b4= be.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    var l8 = document.createElement("h1");
    l8.innerHTML="After";
    var l88 = document.createElement("h1");
    l88.innerHTML="Before";
    if (b4[0].innerHTML == "Before")
    {
        be.replaceChild(l8, b4[0]);
    }
    else if (b4[0].innerHTML=="After")
    {
        be.replaceChild(l88, b4[0]);
    }
}
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suska/6mkxB/)

Comment: Thank you very much, you and CBroe were very helpful. I would have accepted CBroe's answer. But something visual goes a long way for beginners like me.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what’s been said in comments already:

```
var l8 = document.createElement("h1").innerHTML="After";
var l88 = document.createElement("h1").innerHTML="Before";
```

After this your variables do not contain references to the created elements, but the string values that you assigned to their innterHTML. (The result of an assignment operation is the assigned value.) And trying to pass text values instead of element references to replaceChild afterwards must fail for that reason.

Do this in two steps – create the elements first and save their reference into the variables – and then manipulate their innerHTML afterwards.

```
var l8 = document.createElement("h1");
l8.innerHTML="After";
var l88 = document.createElement("h1");
var l88 = .innerHTML="Before";
```

(And maybe use better suited variable names, because if you keep your current “naming scene” up you’ll get confused sooner or later.)

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the following, for better readability:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
    function toggleText() {
         var be= document.getElementById("main");
         var b4= be.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];

         if (b4.innerHTML=="Before") { 
             b4.innerHTML = "After";
         }
         else if (b4.innerHTML=="After") {
             b4.innerHTML = "Before";
         }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="main" onclick="toggleText()">
        <h1>Before</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```